# Proyecto en HTML-JS-CSS + NodeJS en host no funciona

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs, servidor, aplicación-web

Estoy en la hermosa aventura de programar y me surgió un pequeño problema.

Estuve desarrollando una web de contenidos completa en HTML-JS-CSS. Cuando en un momento necesite que se crearán blogs dinámicamente me llevo a tener que usar una app de nodejs paraa creación y el guardado de estos blogs en la carpeta raíz de mí web.

Cuando quería iniciarlo en local poniendo
" Node app.js" para después arrancar toda la web con la app funcional desde "localhost:3000"

*EL PROBLEMA*
Compré un host simple donde la web corre de forma correcta ,pero cuando el usuario clickea para crear el blog personal me sale un error de que no encontró el archivo. Estuve tratando de investigar toda la mañana y es que nunca se ejecuta la app de node. Estoy usando como host donweb.com , que paso debería seguir para que la página ande tal cual como andaba en el local?

La estructura de carpetas es la siguiente

Css
Js
Blogs
Node
Index
Blogs
App(donde está para ejecutar la app y que corra en el puerto 3000)
Packcage
Packcage

Alguien podría guiarme x favor ?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Faltan muchos detalles, podrías acompañarlo de mas información como el nombre del servicio que utilizas, si lo estas usando como maquina virtual o servicios como vercel, o docker. También servirian imagenes de lo que tratas de hacer.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar debes fijarte que el hosting tenga node instalado, como por ejemplo este proveedor de Hosting llamado namecheap.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas veces un hosting compartido es muy limitado y más para aplicaciones hechas con node.